firebase realtime database always ConnectionState.waiting
final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref("messageData/${widget.idKonsultan}${widget.idUser}");

StreamBuilder(
  stream: dbRef.onValue,
  builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final userS = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: userS.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, i) => Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(userS[i]['pesan']),
                Text(userS[i]['pasienataukonsultan'])
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return const Center(
      child: Text('There is something wrong!'),
    );
  },
),

i use firebase realtime database for my project, why this stream builder always get into CircularProgressIndicator()

There are for chat, so there is so many data.
how do i make it realtime in my flutter app ?

It sounds like your app isn't connected to the database. My first step in troubleshooting that would be to check the configuration data, either in firebase_options.dart or in one of the native files that you used from https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup
